# How to get a user matching a role

Tags: linq

I have a bunch of users and each user can belong to multiple roles.

I was trying to write some code to get the users who belong to a certain area and have a particular role.

I came up with:

```
_db.Users.Where(
    x => x.Roles.Contains(n => n.Name == "Some Role Name")
    && x.AreaId == areaId);
```

This doesn't work though. Does anyone know where I'm going wrong, and how I might fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
_db.Users.Where(x => x.Roles.Any(n => n.Name == "Some Role Name")
    && x.AreaId == areaId);
```

Answer (score 2):

You're using a single equals sign `=` for comparison instead of `==` in `&& x.AreaId = areaId`, for one thing. For another, use `Any` instead of `Contains` in `x.Roles.Contains(n => n.Name == "Some Role Name")`.

Answer (score 1):

`Contains()` is looking for a match within the enumeration so you would have to pass it a `Role` instance - you want to pass a lambda with a condition so use `Any()` instead:

```
_db.Users.Where(x => x.Roles.Any(n => n.Name == "Some Role Name")
                && x.AreaId == areaId);
```

Comment: I think you'll find that has the eoor Operator '&&' cannot be applied to operands of type 'bool' and 'int'